# Send Ajax Variables with POST to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to find the best way to send variables from Javascript to PHP without GET method. I found a way to send through POST method with AJAX:

```
<form method="POST" id="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="image_upload[]" id="img1" />
                <input type="file" name="image_upload[]" id="img2" />
                <input type="file" name="image_upload[]" id="img3" />
                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" />
                <textarea class="intext" name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state" disabled="true" />
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" disabled="true" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" />
            </form>
```

And I am trying to submit the form with jQuery:

```
$('#post').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cpage.php",
        data: {
            'variable1': 'content var1',
                'variable2': 'content var2'
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#post'), $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
        },
        error: function (name, err, desc) {
            alert(desc);
        }
    });
```

**NOTE:** the variable "*position*" has been declared before and works fine.

**Result:** I get "*Internal Server Error*" in the alert. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is in the PHP (or possibly a .htaccess file).  Please post the PHP.

Comment: FYI you can't upload files/images using ajax alone without a hidden iframe or the HTML5 File API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All - show us what is going on the server side.

And now about the files being sent:

You should use `FormData` element for file submit threw Ajax, its not supported by old browser, the browsers that would support this are : ie>9, chrome > 7, opera > 12 safari >5, android > 3 gecko mobile > 2, opera mobile >12.

Use something like this:

```
    $('#post').submit(function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();

        if( window.FormData !== undefined ) //make sure that we can use FormData
        {

            var formData = new FormData($('form#post'));
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "cpage.php",
                                data: formData ,
                                //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type. 
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                success: function (data) {
                                                       console.log(data); // <- for debugging
                                                       $('#post'), $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
                               },
                               error: function (name, err, desc) {
                                     alert(desc);
                               }
                        });
            } else {
                //fallback 
            }
      });
```

As you can see I added `console.log(data)`, try looking at the returned data to identify any other problems.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But, the page don't reach cpage.php (so, hence there are no server side). And I don't need to send the formData because I can use PHP to receive that data, right? I only need to send two javascript variables through POST method.